# Custom angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter data similar to the following:

```
data = {
  ABC: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  DEFG: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  HI: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  JK: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem"
}
```

against an array such as:

```
myArray = ["HI","LMN","ABC"]
```

I am trying to return the pairs for which the key is not present in `myArray`

I have tried the following with no success:

```
$scope.filteredResults = $filter("filter")(data, function (val, index) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (index === myArray[i]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
})
```

Comment: Honestly, this is just a general JavaScript `Array.prototype.filter` question...

Comment: Do you have an angular filter named "filter"? $filter is a service for getting existing filters, you define a new one using the module.filter() syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't `data` be an array? The filter's first parameter must be an `Array` according to the docs. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index of the Object is its key then you can just check if it exists in the array by using [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). I am assuming that `index` is the object's key?

```
$scope.filteredResults = $filter("filter")(data, function(val, index) {
  return myArray.indexOf(index) === -1;
})
```

If you want to return a filtered object, excluding any keys that are present in the filter list, you can filter by keys and then reduce the object based on the allowed keys.

Here's a pure JavaScript implementation of filtering an object with a blacklist.

```js
var data = {
  ABC: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  DEFG: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  HI: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  JK: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem"
};
var blackList  = ["HI", "LMN", "ABC"];

var filtered = Object.keys(data).filter(function(key) {
  return blackList.indexOf(key) === -1;
}).reduce(function(result, key) {
  result[key] = data[key];
  return result;
}, {});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filtered, null, '  ');
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

Comment: I was so caught up with angulars filtering that I forgot about proto filter... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in `controller`, why not just do it in plain JavaScript?

**FYI:** Doing these simple things in Plain JavaScript will be faster than doing it in Angular Utilities.

```js
var data = {
  ABC: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  DEFG: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  HI: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem",
  JK: "Lorem Ipsum lorem lorem"
};

var myArray = ["HI", "LMN", "ABC"];
var keys = Object.keys(data);

var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (myArray.indexOf(keys[i]) == -1) {
    result[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```